# Split the string contained within <> symbol and remove the symbol in Java

Tags: java, string, split

I have a string as

```
String str = "<Java><SQL>";
```

and I want to store it in String[ ] after removing <> symbol as:

```
String[] str1 = "Java,SQL";
```

Also I want to make it iterative i.e. each time I have a new string it should just remove <> and append the different parts in the previous String[].

I looked up at different ways like split() method or matches() method but I am not able to do it.

Comment: try first cutting off the outside `<` and `>` and then split on `><`.

Comment: Have you looked into the Scanner class? ([tag:java-util-scanner])

Comment: Do you want to be able to escape the `<` and `>` characters such that they can be included in the enclosed text?  Do you want to handle mismatched angle brackets, and if so, how?

Comment: str.substring(1, str.length()-1).replace("><",",")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Remove the trailing `<` and `>`
2. Split on `><`

This can be done in one line:

```
final String[] split = "<Java><SQL>".replaceAll("(?:^<)|(?:>$)", "").split("><");
```

If you want to concatenate successive input strings then you need to use a `List`, as an array is of fixed length.

If you pull with splitting into a utility method:

```
public static void main(final String args[]) {
    final List<String> myStrings = new LinkedList<>();
    final String s = "<Java><SQL>";
    myStrings.addAll(split(s));
    System.out.println(myStrings);
    myStrings.addAll(split(s));
    System.out.println(myStrings);
    myStrings.addAll(split(s));
    System.out.println(myStrings);
    myStrings.addAll(split(s));
    System.out.println(myStrings);
}

public static List<String> split(final String in) {
    return Arrays.asList(in.replaceAll("(?:^<)|(?:>$)", "").split("><"));
}
```

Output:

```
[Java, SQL]
[Java, SQL, Java, SQL]
[Java, SQL, Java, SQL, Java, SQL]
[Java, SQL, Java, SQL, Java, SQL, Java, SQL]
```

Comment: When I try to do this it shows error as "The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>" at  "public static List<String> split(final String in)" and also at "final List<String> myStrings = new LinkedList<>();"

Comment: You are using Java 6. You need `= new LinkedList<String>();`.

Comment: Got the fix for issue! I imported java.util.List.Earlier I was importing java.awt.List.Both have List method but former is the generic type while awt.List is used as display element.Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 2):

Basiclly wyxz answer.

```
str1.substring(1, str1.length() - 1).replace("><", ", ").
```